# mdadm RAID1: can you grow to 3 disks, then revert back to 2?

Tags: centos, mdadm, raid1, mirror

I have a Linux (CentOS7) software RAID1 system with two disks which are getting old.  One has been starting to show signs of failure.  I'd like to phase these disks out one at a time with new disks but always have a fully mirror active.

I was thinking to add a third new disk for a 3-way mirror, then fail out an old disk, repeat with another new one, then fail out the second old disk.  That way I'd always have a mirror and not wait for a raid rebuild after a fail event.

This seems like it could work with num-devices=3 and grow, but, when I'm done how do I 'shrink' it back to two devices?  I can't seem to find a reference to what I'm attempting.

Comment: [yes you can](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/A_guide_to_mdadm#Raid_1).

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you may eventually [shrink your array](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/A_guide_to_mdadm#Removing_a_disk_from_an_array) by issuing a `mdadm --grow` command. (Even if the whole point of this procedure is to lower the chances of a loss, do not forget to make sure your data is backed up — human errors just happen).

Note that loop devices give you a convenient way to test and refine your procedure. Here is a complete example.

Create four block devices and one RAID1 array out of two of them, format and mount it:

```
$ fallocate -l 521MiB avolume1
$ fallocate -l 521MiB avolume2
$ fallocate -l 521MiB avolume3
$ fallocate -l 521MiB avolume4
$ sudo losetup -f avolume1
$ sudo losetup -f avolume2
$ sudo losetup -f avolume3
$ sudo losetup -f avolume4
$ sudo mdadm --create --run -n 2 -l 1 /dev/md17 /dev/loop0 /dev/loop1
mdadm: Note: this array has metadata at the start and
...
mdadm: array /dev/md17 started.
$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [raid10]
md17 : active raid1 loop1[1] loop0[0]
      532480 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
$ sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/md17
mke2fs 1.46.2 (28-Feb-2021)
...
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done
$ sudo mount /dev/md17 /mnt
```

Grow the array, adding a third block device:

```
$ sudo mdadm --grow /dev/md17 -n 3 --add /dev/loop2
mdadm: added /dev/loop2
raid_disks for /dev/md17 set to 3
$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [raid10]
md17 : active raid1 loop2[2] loop1[1] loop0[0]
      532480 blocks super 1.2 [3/3] [UUU]
```

Fail and remove one of the initial block devices from the array:

```
$ sudo mdadm /dev/md17 --fail /dev/loop0
mdadm: set /dev/loop0 faulty in /dev/md17
$ sudo mdadm /dev/md17 --remove /dev/loop0
mdadm: hot removed /dev/loop0 from /dev/md17
$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [raid10]
md17 : active raid1 loop2[2] loop1[1]
      532480 blocks super 1.2 [3/2] [_UU]
```

Add the fourth block device to the array:

```
$ sudo mdadm /dev/md17 --add /dev/loop3
mdadm: added /dev/loop3
$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [raid10]
md17 : active raid1 loop3[3] loop2[2] loop1[1]
      532480 blocks super 1.2 [3/3] [UUU]
```

Remove the second of the initial block devices from the array:

```
$ sudo mdadm /dev/md17 --fail /dev/loop1
mdadm: set /dev/loop1 faulty in /dev/md17
$ sudo mdadm /dev/md17 --remove /dev/loop1
mdadm: hot removed /dev/loop1 from /dev/md17
$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [raid10]
md17 : active raid1 loop3[3] loop2[2]
      532480 blocks super 1.2 [3/2] [U_U]
```

Finally, grow (shrink) the array:

```
$ sudo mdadm --grow -n 2 /dev/md17
raid_disks for /dev/md17 set to 2
$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [raid10]
md17 : active raid1 loop3[3] loop2[2]
      532480 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a 'dying' drive, as suggested by SMART, in a RAID10 config.
I was looking for a similar solution, so as not to degrade the array before adding the new drive. I used `mdadm --replace` and did what I had hoped, synced the new drive then set the dying drive as faulty.  Note, need to have added the new drive as spare before issuing the replace command

```
$> mdadm /dev/md0 --add /dev/new
$> mdadm /dev/md0 --replace /dev/old
```

Note: if you add /dev/new when array is in degraded mode, it will not be added as a spare, but the array with start to rebuild.

Note on RAID10:
Adding and growing a raid10 does not change the layout, ie n2 --> n3 (3way mirror), since an odd number of disks can exist in a mdadm software raid10.

Answer (score -1):

```
mdadm /dev/<md> --fail <real_dev>    # first fail the disk
mdadm /dev/<md> --remove <real_dev>  # then remove it
```

Comment: I think you meant `mdadm` not `mdraid`, and you need to grow the number of disks back down to 2 from 3 ( `mdadm -G /dev/mdX -n 2` )... simply failing and removing one of the drives will leave it degraded.

Comment: Yes, thank you.